# Can I use probabilistic label when train model in logistic regression?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I use `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` and would like to use probabilistic label when train model.

But as following code I got error when I attempt to use train data with probability label for training logistic regression model.

Is there an any way to use probablity label for training logistic regression model?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

x = np.array([1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970,
              1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975,
              1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980,
              1981, 1982, 1983, 1984]).reshape(-1, 1)

y = np.array([0.003, 0.016, 0.054, 0.139, 0.263,
              0.423, 0.611, 0.758, 0.859, 0.903,
              0.937, 0.954, 0.978, 0.978, 0.982,
              0.985, 0.989, 0.988, 0.992])

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x, y)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-6f0a54f18841> in <module>()
     13 
     14 lr = LogisticRegression()
---> 15 lr.fit(x, y)  # => ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

/home/sudot/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1172         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64,
   1173                          order="C")
-> 1174         check_classification_targets(y)
   1175         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
   1176         n_samples, n_features = X.shape

/home/sudot/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    170     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    171             'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 172         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    173 
    174 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logistic Regression is a binary classification model. You can't pass non-categorical values as target.

Just round values of y before fitting.

```
y = y.round(0)  # Add this line

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x, y)
```